# Permutation as a product of generators of the permutation group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $G$ be a permutation group, generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_n$. And let $h$ be in $G$.

> Example: $G=\langle (12)(34),(123)\rangle$ and $h=(12)(34)(123)=(243)$ (reading the cycles from right to left, as I learned it)

Question: Knowing $h$ and knowing that $h$ is in $G$. How to I obtain the decompsotion of $h$ in a product of the $g_i$?

> In the Example: $h=(243) = ... = g_1 \circ g_2$

My ideas: Maybe use the matrix representation of $h$ and the $g_i$?

Comment: It's a good question, but it would take too long to give an adequate answer. If you are looking for an expression for $h$ of minimal or close to minimal length, then it is a very ahrd problem - think of the Rubik's cube group.

Comment: If the group is not too big, say of order up to a million (or probably larger if you are serious about it), then a computer can just construct the complete Cayley graph, and then it can read off a shortest expression for any element.

Comment: Yeah, I read about that in the 'sage' help. But my problem indeed concerns the Rubik's cube group.

Should the problem... (a) Find a shortest combination of generators of $G$ that is equal to an element of $G$, i.e. to a known combination of moves

...not be easier than the typical problem (b): For a given position of the cube, find the shortest way to the solved position

?

Comment: According to your statement of the problem, you are given $h$ as a permutation, so we are talking about (b) rather than (a). But I think (a) and (b) are essentially equivalent anyway. Unless the given word for $g$ was already the shortest (in which case the problem would be trivial), I don't know whether having a given word for $g$ would help you find the shortest word. Maybe you should as some Rubik cube experts about that!